# Live tile doesn't work after upgrading the project from WP7 to WP8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Live tile doesn't work after upgrading the project from WP7 to WP8. Does anyone know the reason?
I've done an custom tile, and I'm saving it as a picture in IsolatedStorage.
The code for Tile in Scheduled Agent:

```
.
.
.

ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
                   if (tile != null)
                   {
                       FlipTileData data = new FlipTileData()
                       {
                           SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + mediumTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                           BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + mediumTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                           WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + wideTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                       };

                   tile.Update(data);
               }
NotifyComplete();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use an image in your IsolatedStorage, you need to use the /Shared/ShellContent path. Here is your code with the fix:

```
ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();
                   if (tile != null)
                   {
                       FlipTileData data = new FlipTileData()
                       {
                           SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + mediumTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                           BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + mediumTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                           WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/" + wideTile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                       };

                   tile.Update(data);
               }
NotifyComplete();
```